# Spring RequestMapping with regex

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

I am facing the similar problem as this one, [How to correct Spring MVC RequestMapping order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410609/how-to-correct-spring-mvc-requestmapping-order). So I tried the solution from the answer, it works fine.

The answer is using regex, `{user:^(?!api).*}`, it looks like everything starting with "api" is matched(excluded). I want to do exact match, and have tried couple ways including `{user:^(?!api)}` with no luck. Is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: An exact match that includes "api" or excludes it? Also, can you provide details of exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. The string is matched to be excluded, that is, for the API call, /{user/**, when the user=api, the request will NOT be be accepted by this endpoint. Instead, the request will be taken care by another endpoint starting /api/{user}/**.
Tried several combination, cannot remember exactly.

Comment: So, you want to dis-allow "api/{user}", but want to allow something like "apix/{user}"?

Comment: say a request is /api/user1, this one will be dis-allowed for /{user}/**, but it will be handled by /api/{user}/**.

Comment: found a similar discussion with different approach, [How to define RequestMapping prioritization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647346/how-to-define-requestmapping-prioritization)