# Request Mapping with Multiple Wildcards

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

I want to have two endpoints that have wild cards in the @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method = { RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")

@RequestMapping(value="/**/versions/{versionId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")
```

When I perform a request that should go to `/**/versions/{versionId}` it is  preferring the `/**` endpoint over the `/**/versions/{versionId}` endpoint even though the request should match.

I am using:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.SR2</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try regex instead of wildcard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410609/how-to-correct-spring-mvc-requestmapping-order

Comment: Can you have regex that works on the directory structure? They seem to only work for that one section between the slashes e.g. 

If you have "/*." on the request mapping, that will work for /test but not /test/test2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to change the order of your `@RequestMapping` methods.

For me works `http://localhost:8080/versions/1` returns `version 1`.

And for any other request without `version/{versionId}` it returns `index`.

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/**/versions/{versionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String version(@PathVariable String versionId){
        return "version " + versionId;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add a path variable on the mapping for some reason it does not work, any ideas why?

@RequestMapping(value = {"{p1}"})

Comment: @Barnesy What does not work? Is it working without PathVariable and just reorder the methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you want quite complicated request mapping try to overwrite handleRequest as it is here: [How to define RequestMapping prioritization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647346/how-to-define-requestmapping-prioritization)
Than you can:

```
if (urlPath.contains("/versions")) {
    /* forward to method with @RequestMapping(value="/get/versions/{versionId}")
}
```

Instead of:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**/versions/{versionId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")
```

use:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/response_for_versions/{versionId}", method = { RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "application/json")
```

Now all ".../versions/{versionId}" should be forwarded to "/response_for_versions/{versionId}" and all others would be handled by "/**"

Comment: 1) This will result in an infant loop because of the if condition.
2) There is a reason for the /**, I want to get the value from that.

Comment: You are right. My bad. Maybe you can forward to requestMapping which does not contain string "/versions" for example "/response_for_versions/{versionId}". Just the thought.